# In Beresheit what is the difference between the light in 1:3 and the light in 1:14

Tags: words, parashat-bereishit

I notice that in 1.3, the word אוֺר  ("ore") is used, but in 1.14, the word  מְאֹרֹת
(morot) is used. I see that both contain aleph and reish.

Both have something to do with light and lighting up. However, in one a verb and the other a noun? Or, can "ore" be use as a noun or a verb? I find this very confusing.

Comment: Hey Victoria, welcome to Mi Yodeya! ....I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here....perhaps is your confusion coming from thinking that אור and מאורות are the same thing? ....if you look at the verses in context, you will find that there are really two different things under discussion. In the first verse you quoted ([1:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165#v=3&showrashi=true)), the God creates light. In the second ([1:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165#v=14&showrashi=true)), God creates the Sun and the Moon, the "luminaries." Both are nouns.

Answer (score 6):

אור is a singular noun meaning "light". מאורות (expanded form) is a plural noun meaning "[things that] give off light". You are correct in noticing that they share the root of אור.

Comment: אור can also be a verb. eg הבוקר אור והאנשים שלחו...

Comment: @double or an adjective. Or a part of speech that has no good English name.